# Reading in Poor CSV File Structure

Tags: r, csv, pandas, readr

I am trying to read in a large  csv datafile (delimited by ,), and I keep on getting stuck on rows such as the following:
link to raw file: "http://daniels-pull.universityofdenv.netdna-cdn.com/assets/GeneralOccurrencesAll.csv"

```
| RIN    | UCR_Group | Loc                                         |
|--------|-----------|---------------------------------------------|
|490658  | Property  | 400 BLOCK 17TH ST, 5TH FL                   |
|506928  | Disorder  | 1400 BLOCK W COLORADO AVE, COLORADO SPRINGS |
```

As you can see, the delimiter for the file is used in the column as well. Is there a way to specify the delimiter for a column as a regular expression to read in the file, or would I need to look into using read.fwf to find the max length of each field, and parse the data using that? 
Currently, this is my code that I have came up with so far:

```
datafile <- "http://daniels-pull.universityofdenv.netdna-cdn.com/assets/GeneralOccurrencesAll.csv"
new <-readr::read_delim(datafile, sep ='[\\S],[\\S]')  
new <-read.table(datafile, sep ='[\\S],[\\S]' )
```

Should I be using read.fwf, or trying to pull out the problem column manually? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

For Bonus points, I'd really like to build a function that would detect columns that are bad in a csv file, or data that looks like it may mess up the structure of the file, such as this case. That way, I don't have to mess around with a text editor, and can programmatically find these errors in the file. Thoughts on how to build something like this?

Comment: Yes readr::read_csv works, but with errors. I was hoping I could supply a regular expression as the delimiter in R, but I guess not. I'm just wondering if there is a more elegant way, such as read.table or pulling in the data column by column with fread that may be easier.

Comment: If its even possible to do in pandas, that would be fantastic, but I'd prefer r. I know the structure of my data is bad based on this website: http://csvlint.io/validation/5872bb3e3738390004000005

Comment: @petergensler I think @darshan-baral means the original `read.csv` from base R

Comment: no I don't think read.csv works...I get this error: read.csv(datafile, header = TRUE, sep = '[\\S],[\\S]')
Error in scan(file, what = "", sep = sep, quote = quote, nlines = 1, quiet = TRUE,  : 
  invalid 'sep' value: must be one byte

Comment: You could use `readLines` to suck the data in and then do some splitting and fixing post-hoc. There's really no easy way to deal with this unfortunately without some semi-manual adjustment.

Comment: `count.fields(file, sep=",")` can also be useful for debugging the rows where you have an excess of commas.

Comment: @thelatemail how would you go about using read lines? Can you provide a mwe?

Comment: @petergensler - `readLines("filename")` is about as minimal as it gets :-)

Comment: Have you tried `read.csv(file, fill=TRUE)`? The file seems to read fine (and has 15 columns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `panda.read_csv` and regex negative look ahead.  The same regex should work in `R` as well.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=r',(?!\s)')
```

Filter `df` for rows in which `LOC` has a comma, to verify that we've parsed correctly:

```
df[df.LOC.str.contains(',')]
```

[image]

Comment: How did you design your regular expression? I've been trying to make that for days......where do you test your regex's at?

Answer (score 2):

Replace each comma that is surrounded by non-space with semicolon and then read in the result using `read.csv2`.

(Replace `Lines` with `readLines(u)` command to read it from `u`.  Also if there are semicolons in the file then use a different character and specify it in the `sep=` argument to `read.csv2` or just `read.csv` and in the second arg to `gsub`.)

```
read.csv2(text = gsub(",(\\S)", ";\\1", Lines)))
```

giving:

```
     RIN UCR_Group                                         Loc
1 490658  Property                   400 BLOCK 17TH ST, 5TH FL
2 506928  Disorder 1400 BLOCK W COLORADO AVE, COLORADO SPRINGS
```

**Note:** We used this as the input `Lines`:

```
Lines <- c("RIN,UCR_Group,Loc", 
  "490658,Property,400 BLOCK 17TH ST, 5TH FL", 
  "506928,Disorder,1400 BLOCK W COLORADO AVE, COLORADO SPRINGS")
```

**Update:** It seems in the actual file that a space can appear before a valid comma separator and there are one character fields so we modified the pattern accordingly.  Here is the result for the first 3 lines of the file:

```
u <- "http://daniels-pull.universityofdenv.netdna-cdn.com/assets/GeneralOccurrencesAll.csv"
Lines <- readLines(u, 3)

read.csv2(text = gsub(",(\\S)", ";\\1", Lines))
```

giving:

```
     RIN               UCR_Group                            UCR_Cat
1 416667 Crimes Against Property Criminal Mischief/Damaged Property
2 416673  Crimes Against Persons              Forcible Sex Offenses
              EXP_TRANSLATION         OCC_DATE OCC_TIME                     LOC
1 CRIMINAL MISCHIEF - MTR VEH 1/1/2010 0:00:00      145  200 BLOCK S ZENOBIA ST
2             SEX ASLT - RAPE 1/1/2010 0:00:00      300 1500 BLOCK S DECATUR ST
  TRANSLATION       PIN               DOB SEX          X          Y     LON
1 VICTIM      235602181  5/6/1979 0:00:00   M 3126041.08 1684996.73 -105.05
2 ARRESTEE    219220590 3/19/1988 0:00:00   M 3134340.56 1676360.06 -105.02
    LAT
1 39.71
2 39.68
```

Comment: I don't think this works with the original data file, but it does work with the vector supplied like you stated.

Comment: Seems the descrption in the question is not entirely accurate as there are valid comma separators that are prefaced with a space.  Also there are one character fields whereas there were none in the short example. I have modified the code accordingly so it should work on the file.

Comment: Apologies for that. I should have been more clear. Building on your answer, how would you use your logic to search for any delimiter in a file that would throw off parsing it correctly? I'm sure so many other people have run into a similar issue

Comment: Are there any resources to learn about using text connections to read files into R? This seems like such a handy feature, but I doubt anyone is familiar with how to leverage it properly

Comment: Building on your approach, this is how I was able to clean up my file:system.time(genocc <- readr::read_file(datafile))
system.time(test <- str_replace_all(genocc, ",(?!\\s)", ";"))
file <- readr::read_delim(file = test, delim = ";")

Answer (score 1):

You know which field has the non-escaped commas:

```
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

txt <- readr::read_lines("http://daniels-pull.universityofdenv.netdna-cdn.com/assets/GeneralOccurrencesAll.csv")
commas <- stri_locate_all_fixed(txt, ",")

map2_chr(txt[1:100], commas[1:100], function(x, y) {
  len <- nrow(y)
  bits <- c(1:6, (len-6):len)
  for (i in bits) { stri_sub(x, y[i,1], y[i,2]) <- ";" }
  x
}) -> rd

read.table(text=rd, header=TRUE, sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>%
  dplyr::glimpse()
## Observations: 99
## Variables: 14
## $ RIN             <int> 416667, 416673, 416674, 416680, 416684, 416686...
## $ UCR_Group       <chr> "Crimes Against Property", "Crimes Against Per...
## $ UCR_Cat         <chr> "Criminal Mischief/Damaged Property", "Forcibl...
## $ EXP_TRANSLATION <chr> "CRIMINAL MISCHIEF - MTR VEH", "SEX ASLT - RAP...
## $ OCC_DATE        <chr> "1/1/2010 0:00:00", "1/1/2010 0:00:00", "1/1/2...
## $ OCC_TIME        <int> 145, 300, 500, 730, 200, 440, 100, 851, 140, 2...
## $ LOC.TRANSLATION <chr> "200 BLOCK S ZENOBIA ST,VICTIM     ", "1500 BL...
## $ PIN             <int> 235602181, 219220590, 119013720, 174326399, 32...
## $ DOB             <chr> "5/6/1979 0:00:00", "3/19/1988 0:00:00", "5/25...
## $ SEX             <chr> "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "...
## $ X               <dbl> 3126041, 3134341, 3134360, 3127695, 3193317, 3...
## $ Y               <dbl> 1684997, 1676360, 1700160, 1682545, 1708673, 1...
## $ LON             <dbl> -105.05, -105.02, -105.02, -105.04, -104.81, -...
## $ LAT             <dbl> 39.71, 39.68, 39.75, 39.70, 39.77, 39.78, 39.7...
```

Comment: Wow, that is truly wonderful! How would you go about writing a function to detect which fields are bad from within R? Is that even possible, rather than searching manually in a text editor?

Comment: Aye, tis possible. Find the common "comma" pattern and then isolate the field with the errant one.

Comment: Ok, you want to advise on how to build a function that could do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a worked example showing you can use a regex to parse this file, relying on the fact that the commas in the addresses have a space. This of course gets more complicated if this rule doesn't always hold:

```
txt <- "RIN,UCR_Group,Loc
123456,Property,1 STREET
490658,Property,400 BLOCK 17TH ST, 5TH FL
506928,Disorder,1400 BLOCK W COLORADO AVE, COLORADO SPRINGS"

dat <- readLines(textConnection(txt))
# in a real example:
# dat <- readLines("filename.csv")

spl <- strsplit(dat, "(?<=\\S),(?=\\S)", perl=TRUE)
setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, spl[-1])), spl[[1]])

#     RIN UCR_Group                                         Loc
#1 123456  Property                                    1 STREET
#2 490658  Property                   400 BLOCK 17TH ST, 5TH FL
#3 506928  Disorder 1400 BLOCK W COLORADO AVE, COLORADO SPRINGS
```